# hasPermission of UndefinedNd

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a problem:
My bot crash on my main server when I add role Member (reuuu on dev server) and on dev server, with role reuuu works perfectly.
I don’t understand the error.

```
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of null
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:96:23)
    at Client.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/container/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/container/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:825:20)
```

And here is the code
https://hastebin.com/ziqadekivo.js

Comment: It means that `message.member` is null

Answer (score 0):

As [@Seblor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3670132/seblor) said in comment, it means the `message.member` is `null`, this happens when the message is not sent in a server or the user has left the server. I noticed you check if it is a DM channel at the top, since you are using message.member a better check would be `if (message.member === null) return;` as this would ensure there is a member object and as a side effect not work in DM channels.

Comment: OK @Tom ! Thanks, I am going to try with ```if(message.member === null) return;```; so you think this will resolve the problem; because I only see this error on one of my server using bot ?

Comment: It would stop you getting the error in the question

Comment: Didn't realize you had so many message handlers... I would recommend combining them into a single message handler maybe use a Map or an object to decide what command to run. If you get the cannot read property `hasPermission` of `null` error, you can avoid this by going to the specified line and adding `message.member !== null  &&` in the if statement before `message.member.hasPermission`

Comment: So I add ˋˋ`if(message.member !== null  &&) return;`ˋ` after line 96

Comment: @coera no. What I meant was change `if (message.member.hasPermission( /* ... */) )` to `if (message.member !== null && message.member.hasPermission( /* ... */ ) )`